# Best solution for storing / accessing large Integer arrays for a web application

Tags: sql, design-patterns, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Web Application (Java backend) that processes a large amount of raw data that is uploaded from a hardware platform containing a number of sensors.

Currently the raw data is uploaded and the data is decompressed and stored as a 'text' field in a Postgresql database to allow the users to log in and generate various graphs / charts of the data (using a JS charting library clientside).

Example string...

[45,23,45,32,56,75,34....]

The arrays will typically contain ~300,000 values but this could be up to 1,000,000 depending on how long the sensors are recording so the size of the string being stored could be a few hundred kilobytes

This currently seems to work fine for now as there are only ~200 uploads per day but as I am looking at the scalability of the application and the ability to backup the data I am looking at alternatives for storing this data

DynamoDB looked like a great option for me as I can carry on storing the uploads details in my SQL table and just save a URL endpoint to be called to retrieve the arrays....but then I noticed the item size is limited to 64kb

As I am sure there are a million and one ways to do this I would like to put this out to the SO community to hear what others would recommend, either web services or locally stored....considering performance, scalability, maintainability etc etc...

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Just to clarify the data shown above is just the 'Y' values as it is time-sampled the X values are taken as the position in the array....so I dont think storing as a tuple would have any benefits.

Comment: Maybe you should look for a DBMS that is optimized to work with tuples... Probably, not a Relational-DBMS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to store such strings, you probably want to use [**S3**](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (1 object containing 
the array string), in this case you will have "backup" out of the box by enabling bucket
versioning.

Comment: Ah I didnt realise this was possible with S3, thanks!

Comment: If you are accessing it via HTTP there is also another little trick that is gzipping the array (json) before putting the object on S3, and setting the Content-Encoding: gzip on the object so you can reduce latency when retriving it or sending it to a client.

Answer (score 0):

You can try tuple of Couchbase and ElasticSearch. Couchbase is very fast document-oriented NoSql database. Several thousands of insert operation is normal for CB. Item size is limited to 20MB. Performance of "get" operation is several tens of thousands. There is one disadvantage, you can query data only by id (there is "view", but I think it will be too difficult to adapt them to the plotting). Compensate for this deficiency may ElasticSearch, that can perform any query very fast. Format data in Couchbase and ElasticSearch is json-document.

Comment: Thanks @vakoroteev I had not seen these options, Ideally I would like a fully managed and hosted solution to make my life easy, querying would not be an issue as I am simply storing the 'key' as a pointer in my SQL DB and then dumping the String in the browser for my javascript plotting library to draw.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across Google Cloud Datastore, which allows me to store single item Strings up to 1Mb (un-indexed), seems like a good alternative to Dynamo

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [SSDB](https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), both are designed to store large list(array) of data. The difference between these two databases is that Redis is memory only(disk for backup), but SSDB is disk based and uses memory as cache.